# Missing the fundamentals of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Can some one explain why this doesn't work:

```
private static $bundles = array(
    'page-builder' => array(
        'Freya\\Bundle\\PageBuilder' => self::$baseDir . '/freya-bundle-pagebuilder/Freya/Bundle/PageBuilder'
    );
);
```

`self::$baseDir` is `__DIR__`. I thought at run time PHP would evaluate this and save it out as `path/to/some/dir/freya- ....`

The exact error is:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$baseDir' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS) in /vagrant/local-dev/content/mu-plugins/Freya-MU/bundles/BundleLoader.php on line 51**

Line 51, is: `'Freya\\Bundle\\PageBuilder' => self::$baseDir . '/freya-bundle-pagebuilder/Freya/Bundle/PageBuilder'`

So ... What am I missing and whats the proper way to do this?

**PHP Version:** 5.5

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump(self::$baseDir)`?

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not allow this.  PHP properties may be initialized to constant values, but only with constant values that are available at *compile time*.  From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Whatever value your static property `$baseDir` holds is simply not available until the class definition is actually executed (i.e. runtime).

You can get around this to a degree by using a class *constant*:

```
class AClass {
    const MY_CONSTANT = 42;

    protected $property = self::MY_CONSTANT;
}
```

Class constants are evaluated at *compile time*, which is what you need to do.  Note however that you cannot do any other manipulations (e.g. initialize `$property` to be `self::MY_CONSTANT * 3`)

I would suggest leaving `self::$baseDir` completely out of your property, and either inject it in during construction or whenever your property is actually being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable when declaring a property in a class. Check out the invalid property declarations in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-204).

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
   // invalid property declarations:
   public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
   public $var2 = <<<EOD
hello world
EOD;
   public $var3 = 1+2;
   public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
   public $var5 = $myVar;
```

This is because PHP doesn't execute any code when parsing/compiling your class.

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to the other answers really: PHP 5.5 doesn't allow expressions, including concatenation, in default value definitions, but 5.6 does. (http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

So, basically, either upgrade your PHP version or set the value of $bundles from a method. There is no problem with your array otherwise.